# How to force CSV download when it reaches the client-side? (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, csv

I am trying to serve up a CSV file as the response to a get request.

If I go onto Dev tools -> Network I can see the CSV values in the response preview, and if I double click that it will download the file. However I can't seem to get it to download automatically.

I have messed around with every type of header I can think of.

Any ideas?

[image: Response Headers]

Comment: Isn't that something you set in Apache?

Comment: How are you making the request in the first place? You've tagged this [tag:ajax]. Are you using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Perhaps check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269568/force-download-csv-file

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361821/download-file-from-ajax-sort-of

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: It is a Jquery $.get() - this does not allow for file downloads?

Comment: @CharlieLynch: Do show your codes as well as the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It seems you can't get file downloads from ajax requests (Thanks to Quentin for the linked answer in the comments), at least not easily anyway.

This is because there is a subtle separation between the user and the browser. Ajax is triggered by the browser so the file is returned to the browser not the user.

A form submit on the other hand is triggered by the user and so the file is returned to the user (automatically downloading).

So in order to fix this I changed to a form with a post method with hidden inputs and it now works a treat.

Thanks all.